# Understanding POIPS of EBS volumes

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

According to aws documentation. `1PIOPS = reads and writes in I/O sizes of 16KB blocks.`

My question is, How much time will I require to copy 1GB data to a volume having 500 PIOPS ?

```
1GB= 1024*1024 KB = 1048576KB
```

Time required

```
t = 1GB /(500*16 KB) = 47 seconds.
```

But I am able to write 1GB file within 19 seconds.

I generated file using following command:

```
openssl rand -out sample.txt -base64 $(( 2**30 * 3/4 ))
```

Then fired following commands.

sync ; time copy.bash sample.txt

Where copy.bash have following contents.

```
cp $1 $2/
sync
```

What am I doing wrong while calculating data ?

Comment: Perhaps Provisioned IOPs guarantees _minimum performance_, but if there's spare capacity, aws gives it to you?

Comment: @Mxx I don't think that is minimum. iostat also show max 500 read+write/sec.